# date("m"); returns the following result for this month... "02" 

Tags: php, function, date

date("m"); returns the following result for this month... "02"

That is fine and dandy, but the problem is, I need to change 02 into February, and not by changing it to date("F");

I need to use the date function to convert the supplied number of 02 into February, is there a way of going about this logically without a bunch of if/else statements??

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use date('F'). I know you say you can't, but what's the reason for not changing m->F?

Comment: @Marc - you're totally missing the point. He wants to convert "02" to "February"

Comment: F is the only possible format specifier to use if you want to "use the date function" to convert a timestamp representing February to the name "February".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While date('F') would be preferred:

```
$monthnames = array(
  '01'=>'January',
  '02'=>'February',
  '03'=>'March'
); // and so on...

echo $monthnames[date("m")];
```

**EDIT**
Adjusting to hitherto unspecified requirement:

```
$ts = mktime (0, 0, 0, date("m"), 1, date("Y"));
```

doc: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: You said you cannot use date('F').  I don't understand what your comment here means.

Comment: i get month number like 01,02...12 , and i want to display month full name using date function.

Comment: @Layric: The only way to do that using `date()` is by doing `date('F', $timestamp)`. If you can't do that, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$convertIntegerToMonth = array(
    1 => 'January',
    2 => 'February',
    3 => 'March',
    ...
);

$number = 2;
echo $convertIntegerToMonth[(int)$number];
?>
```

Comment: Erp.  Either I missed the cast to int, or you ninja-edited.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Forget those arrays! What about localization?

This will convert "02" to "February"

```
<?php
$month = date("m");    // "02"
$newstr = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month));   // "February"
?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it:

`date('F', strtotime("2000-$month-01"))`

Answer (score 0):

This code is working properly:

```
<?php 
    $year = 2016;
    $month = 02;
    echo date("M", mktime(null, null, null,$month+1, null, $year));
?>
```